# Tkinter is there a way to resize the scroll bar in a canvas window

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, listbox, scrollbar

I have made most of this window already, and would prefer to not have to restart because of a hitch with a scrollbar not resizing properly. Problem being that the scrollbars appear way too small for the listboxes and I want them to span the whole height of each box respecitvely, but as of now they can only function if you spam the arrows as the actual scrolling bit can't move for lack of space. Any help would be appreciated, stuck on this for a while now. (Using python 3.8).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


setup = tk.Tk()

setup.title("Set Up Game")
setup.geometry("450x650")
setup.resizable(width=False, height=False)

select_Box = tk.Canvas(setup, width=450, height=496, bg="#cd3636")
select_Box.pack(padx=10)

listbox1 = Listbox(setup, width=33, height=30)
listbox1_win = select_Box.create_window(110,250, window=listbox1)
listbox2 = Listbox(setup, width=33, height=30)
listbox2_win = select_Box.create_window(320,250, window=listbox2)

scroll1 = Scrollbar(setup)
scroll1_win = select_Box.create_window(200,250, window=scroll1)
scroll2 = Scrollbar(setup)
scroll2_win = select_Box.create_window(410,250, window=scroll2)

listbox1.config(yscrollcommand = scroll1.set, selectmode=SINGLE)
scroll1.config(command = listbox1.yview)
listbox2.config(yscrollcommand = scroll2.set, selectmode=SINGLE)
scroll2.config(command = listbox2.yview)

nameArray = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venasaur", "Charmander", "Charmelion", "Charazard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Lucario", "Garchomp", "Gengar", "Snorlax", "Reuniclus", "Joel","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder"]
for item in nameArray:
    listbox1.insert(END, item)

setup.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with the layout then I don't think we need `getList`, or at least don't need that function with more than a dozen if statements.

Comment: Why do you want to put all your widgets in a Canvas? That's a lot of useless complications to compute the coordinates correctly to avoid overlapping. It would be easier to put your listboxes and scrollbars in a Frame with pack of grid and, then put the frame in the canvas with `create_window()` if you really need to have a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Canvas.create_window to place all of your widgets, all you have to do is define the height of your scrollbar (you may need to play around with the numbers a little to get it to the right size).

So the edited snippet from your code will be:

```
scroll1 = Scrollbar(setup)
scroll1_win = select_Box.create_window(200,
                                       250, 
                                       height=480, # this is all you're missing!
                                       window=scroll1)
```